# Import Unity Ads module to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, module, unityads

I had a problem while trying to import Unity ads to my Android Studio project. I found many answers from forum about adding module unity-ads.aar file to android studio.
Android studio window doesn't allow me click finish button to add this file to project.

I enclose the picture showing that android studio doesn't recognize that file.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in its recent update, Android Studio has removed the option to import modules `.arr` file. Now you need to manually import it. Just follow the steps below to add `.arr` file to your project.
Step 1: switch your app to project mode

[image]

Step 2: Create a new directory and name it libs

[image]
[image]

Step 3: Now manually open that directory location in your file explorer and paste `unit-ads.arr`

[image]

Now go to your app-level Gradle and add the module as a dependency

```
    implementation files('../libs/unity-ads.aar')
```

[image]

Also do add `.arr` in the file tree

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.arr'])
```

Now sync the project, and you should be able to use a new module inside your code.
Don't know why Android Studio removed this option and why unity hasn't switched to `mavenCentral()` or any easier solution. But for now, this method works for me.